# Is there any way to infer a generic type of a method using a parameter's generic value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here is a a trimmed down example.  I'd like to be able to infer the return type without having to explicitly declare the generic type.

```
interface Animal {
    name : string
}

interface Dog extends Animal {
    goodBoy : boolean
}

class AnimalFood<A extends Animal> {
    feed( animal : A ) {
        // Do something
    }
}

class AnimalStore<A extends Animal> {
    buyFood( animal : A ) {
        // Do something
    }
}

const findFoodStore = <A extends Animal>( food : AnimalFood<A> ) : AnimalStore<A> => {
    return new AnimalStore<A>();
};

const dogStore = new AnimalFood<Dog>();
const animalFood = findFoodStore( dogStore );  // inferred as AnimalStore<Animal>
const dogFood = findFoodStore<Dog>( dogStore );  // inferred as AnimalStore<Dog>
const moreDogFood : AnimalStore<Dog> = findFoodStore( dogStore );  // inferred as AnimalStore<Dog>
```

The `animalFood` value does not infer the Dog type.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Your `AnimalFood<A>` and `AnimalStore<A>` types are structurally identical to each other and to the empty object type `{}`.  [Unused type parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--) and [empty classes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) mess up type inference.  Presumably these things should care about `A`, right?  Can you add some structural dependence on them?  Is this just example code or do you really have empty classes like this?

Comment: @jcalz Yea, sorry just trying to provide to minimal example.  Edited the example

Comment: [And now it infers as `AnimalStore<Dog>` as desired](https://tsplay.dev/mpLxxm).  I'm failing to see the problem here.

Comment: All right, this is closed as a duplicate, although now the example isn't a [mre] of the issue since things infer as you expect.